# Has word "тачизла" anything to do hip-hop culture in general and to Snoop Dog in particular?

Tags: этимология

So, recently I've found out that my friends do not know word "тачизла" which I used in some casual context. This is a word from my childhood, I've heard it on the streets of my youth pretty often. Then I've realized that, indeed, postfix "-изла" is pretty untypical to Russian language.

Than I've found this question on English SE: [What is the meaning of joke “may it plizzle the cozizzle” in Futurama?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242490/what-is-the-meaning-of-joke-may-it-plizzle-the-cozizzle-in-futurama?newsletter=1&nlcode=31107%7C209c).

Here's an excerpt from accepted answer:

> Snoop Dogg popularized the slang (in black culture in the US) of
>   adding the -izzle suffix (and sometimes infix) to various words. He
>   does it in many songs, including Drop It Like It's Hot and Tha
>   Shiznit. He also does it as a guest in other rappers' songs, such as
>   the intro to Dr. Dre's The Chronic.

So, the question is - what is the origin of word "тачизла"? Is "-изла" related somehow to English "-izzle" postfix?

Comment: To be fair, I have never heard it, too (I was born in late 80s, though). Specifying the region where you found the word might help.

Comment: @Shady_arc, so OK, it's mid 80s - the very beginning of 90s, Moscow region.

Comment: You sure it's not "тачила"? Never heard it, too, but at least Yandex, Google and НКРЯ did.

Comment: @Shady_arc I'm 100% sure. It was definitely used, it surprised me a bit that it can not be found, but not that much. Actually some slang words can be difficultly found even nowadays if their usage was limited to some contexts.

Comment: And what тачизла means? Never heard it before.

Comment: Similar suffixes (`-изл-`) I had heard in russian cartoons about Moomintrolls. And also I know word `тачила`, mentioned above. Probably, it is a combination of them.

Comment: Snoop Dogg's career did not begin until the 1990s, so if you were hearing it from the mid-80s then it was not from anything he did. Though it could be from hip-hop influence of others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning is the same as `тачила (car)`

And suffix `-изла` is totally related to Snoop Dogg
This suffux is not common for russians, honestly, i've never heard it from anybody in person.

But in tv series Scrubs(which is popular in Russia) this suffix was used lots of time to stress afroamerican slang. And in dubbing it was kept the same, for example

> Братизл, садись в мой тачизл, поезем в клубизл

which is the same as

> Брат, садись в мою тачку, поедем в клуб

Comment: I like such exercises )) Yet it is also possible to play around with a foreign (English) root: `За фреймой фейсело. Даркие тундерные свормы разслайсились и вылукаутнули рэдноватые рэи санца`